# $L^p-L^q$ estimates for heat equation - regularizing effect

Tags: heat-equation, regularity-theory-of-pdes, semigroup-of-operators

Where can I find a proof of the following estimate
$$\|S(t)v\|_{L^p(\Omega)}\leq C t^{-\frac{N}{2}\left(\frac{1}{q}-\frac{1}{p}\right)}\|v\|_{L^q(\Omega)}, $$
where $1\leq p<q<+\infty$, $\Omega\subset \mathbb{R}^N$ is an open bounded set and $\{S(t)\}_{t\geq 0}$ is the semigroup generate by the heat equation with Dirichlet boundary condition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer by the OP does not directly address their question because it uses the explicit form of the heat kernel on $\mathbb{R}^N$, while the question is posed for an arbitrary (bounded) domain $\Omega$. Interestingly there is a nice argument to deduce the estimate on $\Omega$ from that on $\mathbb{R}^N$ (see Davies, *Heat Kernels and Spectral Theory*, Theorem 2.1.6):

Let $\Delta$ be the Laplacian on $L^2(\mathbb{R}^N)$, $\Delta_\Omega$ the Laplacian on $L^2(\Omega)$ with Dirichlet boundary conditions, and $\chi$ the characteristic function of $\mathbb{R}^N\setminus \Omega$. By standard results on semigroup convergence, $e^{t(\Delta-n\chi)}f\to e^{t\Delta_\Omega}f$ as $n\to \infty$.

It follows from the Kato-Trotter product formula that
$$
0\leq e^{t\Delta-n\chi}f\leq e^{t\Delta} f
$$
for all positive $f\in L^2(\mathbb{R}^N)$. In the limit $N\to\infty$ it follows that $e^{t\Delta_\Omega}f\leq e^{t\Delta}f$ for all positive $f\in L^2(\Omega)$, which is easily seen to be equivalent to
$$
|e^{t\Delta_\Omega}f|\leq e^{t\Delta}|f|
$$
for all $f\in L^2(\Omega)$.

This shows that the estimate from the question for the semigroup $(e^{t\Delta})$ implies the same bound for $(e^{t\Delta_\Omega})$.

An alternative approach is to notice that the estimate from the question is equivalent to the Sobolev inequality 
$$
\|f\|_{2N/(N-2)}\leq C\|\nabla f\|_2,
$$
which can obviously be localized.

Comment: Very nice. I didn't see that. Thanks to clarify it.

Answer (score 7):

Let $N_t:\mathbb{R}^N\to \mathbb{R}$, $t>0$, be the function defined by
$$N_t(x)=(4\pi t)^{-N/2}e^{-|x|^2/4t}.$$
Since 
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^N} e^{-a|x|^2}dx=\left(\frac{\pi}{a}\right)^{N/2},\tag{1}\label{1}$$
we can see that $N_t\in L^1(\mathbb{R}^N)$ and $\|N_t\|_{ L^1(\mathbb{R}^N)}=1$.

We know that $S(t)v=N_t\ast v$. From [Young's Inequality](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Young's_Inequality_for_Convolutions), we have
$$\|S(t)v\|_{ L^p(\Omega)}\leq \|N_t\ast v\|_{ L^p(\Omega)}\leq \|N_t\|_{ L^m(\Omega)}\|v\|_{ L^q(\Omega)},$$
where $1+\frac{1}{p}=\frac{1}{m}+\frac{1}{q}.$

Now, we just have to estimate $\|N_t\|_{ L^m(\Omega)}$. From \eqref{1}, we can see that
$$\|N_t\|_{ L^m(\Omega)}=(4\pi t)^{-N/2}\left(\int_{\mathbb{R}^N} e^{-\frac{m}{4t}|x|^2}dx\right)^{1/m}=(4\pi t)^{-N/2}\left(\frac{\pi}{\frac{m}{4t}}\right)^{N/2m}=C_{m,N}t^{-\frac{N}{2}\left(1-\frac{1}{m}\right)}=C_{m,N}t^{-\frac{N}{2}\left(\frac{1}{q}-\frac{1}{p}\right)}.$$

Hence, we have the result.

Answer (score 1):

I found the reference **Davies, Heat Kernels and Spectral Theory** 
provided by upstairs to be very useful. Actually, using the pointwise estimates of the heat kernel for the Dirichlet (or neumann) Laplacian in chapter 3 of this book, together with the Young's inequality of convolution, one can prove the  L^p-L^q type estimate for heat semi-group. It is a good exercise  then :)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).